# Handlebars template not rendering data inside of then

Tags: axios, handlebars.js, es6-promise

Im having a problem with handlebars.

This code works:

```
const getFacilitators = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${api_url}/facilitator/list`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('id_token')}`
      }
    })
    return data.Items;
  }

getFacilitators()
  .then(facilitators => {
    if (document.querySelector("#facilitatorTemplate")) {
      var facilitatorTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#facilitatorTemplate").innerHTML);
      document.querySelector("#facilitatorSelect").innerHTML = facilitatorTemplate({ facilitators });
      //element.value = currentFacilitator.id;
    }
  });
```

But it is tripping over a race condition where the `currentFacilitator.id` is not loaded yet. When I try to put it in a `then` after the axios call to get that value then it does not seem to render the values from `facilitators`

```
.then(() => getFacilitators())
.then(facilitators => {
    if (document.querySelector("#facilitatorTemplate")) {
      var facilitatorTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#facilitatorTemplate").innerHTML);
      document.querySelector("#facilitatorSelect").innerHTML = facilitatorTemplate({ facilitators });
      document.querySelector("#facilitatorSelect").value = currentFacilitator.id;
    }
  });
```

[image: Select box is empty]

Here is the HTML

```
<template id="facilitatorTemplate">
                        <select type="text" class="form-control"  name="facilitatorId" list="facilitatorsDatalist" autocomplete="off">
                            {{#each facilitators}}
                                <option value="{{id}}">{{email}}</option>    
                            {{/each}}
                        </select>
                    </template>
                    
                    <div id="facilitatorSelect">waiting</div>
```

Full code is visible here
https://github.com/lindsaymacvean/rp/blob/main/docs/scripts/group.js

Comment: What is `currentFacilitator`. You have a reference to `currentFacilitator.id` but nowhere is `currentFacilitator` defined.

Answer (score 0):

I went line by line through my HTML and realised that one of the other Handlebar renders was taking the innerHTML which included the template I wanted to render. So in effect the HTML was not available by the time it got to the `then` in the chain where I wanted to render my second set of data.

My solution was to store the data from the first axios call in a variable that could be accessed later. Then render all the data in one handlebars template in the last `then` in the chain.